# How to find the availability of an item for a time frame within a time frame

Tags: postgresql

I have an assignment question and I am using postgresql but any general sql guidance will be helpful. The prompt is asking for items that can be rented for 10 days in September after I find the items that fit the budget of $150. It asks for the id, when can the item be rented and the total. So I did the budget with a WITH clause so my query starts as the following

```sql
WITH budget_items (item_id, item_type, total_price) AS (....Logic goes here),
```

I have the items that in the budget and the id and price so I need to figure out the date when they are available if they are. I am not so experienced in SQL and I am not sure how to approach the question. Here are the tables I need:

```
Rentals (rental_id, item_id, customer_id, start_date, end_date, total_price)
Item(item_id, price, type)
```

There are other tables but I don't see how they can be useful. I have another with clause where I filtered out the items rented for the month when the `start_date < September` AND `end_date > September`. But how do I tackle the cases where the item was rented per say 2 times in september and was returned lets say the 19th and there are no more rental for the month so the item is available the 20th. The output is expected to be the item_id, the date is becomes available and the price. Maybe procedures? Is this even possible with SQL?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3